# Obtaining attributes and details of the downloaded dataset(CDS API) using xarray

Tags: python, api, python-xarray

This is the question statement:

The first part of the notebook should include code that invokes the CDS API to download the dataset. It should then open this dataset and print the basic attributes of the dataset, typically the range of latitude, longitude, data variables and other metadata.
Hint: xarray is your library of choice when dealing with large climate datasets.

My code:

```
 import cdsapi

c = cdsapi.Client()

c.retrieve(
    'reanalysis-era5-land',
    {
        'format': 'grib',
        'variable': '2m_temperature',
        'year': '2019',
        'month': '12',
        'day': [
            '01', '02', '03',
            '04', '05', '06',
            '07', '08', '09',
            '10', '11', '12',
            '13', '14', '15',
            '16', '17', '18',
            '19', '20', '21',
            '22', '23', '24',
            '25', '26', '27',
            '28', '29', '30',
            '31',
        ],
        'time': '12:00',
    },
    'download.grib')
```

I have successfully downloaded the dataset and the output looks as follows

```
2020-10-31 15:07:50,657 INFO Welcome to the CDS

2020-10-31 15:07:50,664 INFO Sending request to https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/api/v2/resources/reanalysis-era5-land

2020-10-31 15:07:50,920 INFO Request is completed

2020-10-31 15:07:50,922 INFO Downloading http://136.156.133.25/cache-compute-0008/cache/data7/adaptor.mars.internal-1604136466.9143934-4212-1-0eb95386-8205-41cd-aaa2-9bcec887907b.grib to download.grib (154.8M)

2020-10-31 15:18:19,024 INFO Download rate 252.4K/s    
                                                                
Result(content_length=162325920,content_type=application/x-grib,location=http://136.156.133.25/cache-compute-0008/cache/data7/adaptor.mars.internal-1604136466.9143934-4212-1-0eb95386-8205-41cd-aaa2-9bcec887907b.grib)
```

Can someone tell me how do we display basic attributes of the datasets using xarray with CDS API? I have used jupyter notebook to work on.

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xarray` and `cfgrib` to open the GRIB files.

```py
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_dataset('myfile.grib', engine = 'cfgrib')
```

Then in `ds` you will have all the variables and the attributes of the downloaded file.